# counting the number of character in a text using FileReader

Tags: character, counting

I am new in this superb place. I got help several times from this site. I have seen many answers regarding my question that was previously discussed but i am facing problem to count the number of characters using FileReader. It's working using Scanner. This is what i tried:

```
class CountCharacter
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    File f = new File("hello.txt");
    int charCount=0;
    String c;
    //int lineCount=0;
    if(!f.exists())
    {
        f.createNewFile();
    }
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

while ( (c=br.readLine()) != null) {
String s = br.readLine();
charCount = s.length()-1;
charCount++;


}
System.out.println("NO OF LINE IN THE FILE, NAMED " +f.getName()+ " IS " +charCount);
}
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that each time you go through the loop, you assign the charCount to be the length of the line that iteration of the loop is concerned with. i.e. instead of
`charCount = s.Length() -1;` 
try 
`charCount = charCount + s.Length();`

EDIT:

If you have say the document with the contents "`onlyOneLine`"

Then when you first hit the `while` check the `br.readLine()` will make the `BufferredReader` read the first line, during the `while`'s code block however `br.readLine()` is called again which advances the `BufferredReader` to the second line of the document, which will return `null`. As `null` is assigned to `s`, and you call `length()`, then NPE is thrown.

try this for the while block

`while ( (c=br.readLine()) != null) {
         charCount = charCount + c.Length(); }`

Comment: Thank you adam but it's similar like charCount += s.length()..i tried it but in case of
charCount = s.length();
charCount++;
it was showing expected result +1, thats why i subtract 1.
but i guess it's not the problem, the problem is regarding while condition..It's showing nullPointerException.

Comment: I think it maybe because you are checking in a line is br.readLine() is null in the while condition but then you are writing br.readline() again in the code block. thus s maybe null as the null check does not apply to this next line. so calling s.length may throw NPE